# Shuffle column pairs

Tags: matlab

I have an array with two columns and each row is a unique pair. When I shuffle, I want the array to be shuffled among pairs, not as two separate columns.

This is the array

```
A=[2     1;
   2     1;
   2     2;
   2     2;
   2     3;
   2     3;
   2     4;
   2     4;
   1     5;
   1     6;
   1     7;
   1     8;
   1     9;
   1     9;
   1     9;
   1     9]
```

So after the shuffling, I want the pairs to be preserved, only their ordering can change.

Comment: I don't see 'unique pairs' like you said. Some pairs repeat.

Comment: All pairs are repeated once. Consider they are not repeated. How do you shuffle in pairs? A=[2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 2 4; 1 5; 1 6; 1 7; 1 8; 1 9]

Answer (score 4):

So `size(A) = [16, 2]` and you want to shuffle the rows without disturbing the pairs. Try:

```
A = A(randperm(16), :);
```

`randperm(16)` gives the numbers 1..16 in a random order, and these are used to index the rows of A.